# Как исправить предложение: "Однако в отношении информации о режиме работы..."

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как можно исправить это предложение?

> Однако в отношении информации о режиме работы вышестоящего органа полнота представленности информации по этому параметру выросла почти в четыре раза, и сейчас эти данные размещены на 20 из 48 исследованных сайтов.

Comment: Было бы неплохо написать, что именно вам не нравится в предложении. Возможно отвечающие будут исправлять не то, что вы хотели бы исправить.

Comment: Переписать этот канцелярит с нуля, четко сначала представив, какую именно мысль хочется донести. Представленное проще пристрелить, а не вылечить

Answer (score 1):

Тем не менее, полноту информирования о работе вышестоящего органа характеризует увеличение объема информации о ней почти в четыре раза...

Answer (score 1):

Однако объем представленной информации о работе вышестоящего органа увеличился в 4 раза, и сейчас эти данные размещены на 20 из 48 исследованных сайтов.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл бы понять. **Параметр** какой?  Если параметр и есть "информация о работе органа", то то все переписать начисто. А если нет, то даже трудно подсказать, что тут можно исправить, не понимая терминов "полнота представленности", которая как-то там выросла, и "параметр".